# Difference between 2 varieties of Dockerfiles for running a nodejs app

Tags: docker

I am trying to run a nodejs app as a docker container. I would like to know if there will be any difference in the performance or image size for the following two Dockerfile snippets

```
From ubuntu:14.04  
RUN apt-get install -y nodejs npm
```

and

```
FROM node:4.4.7
```

(assuming the node versions installed are the same)
My understanding is that the first will pull in an ubuntu image and install node on top of it. I am not sure what will happen in the second case. Will this vary based on the native OS?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The node package on hub.docker.com includes their Dockerfile. It's based on a Debian Jessie environment and pulls in multiple build tools from other images:

```
FROM buildpack-deps:jessie

# gpg keys listed at https://github.com/nodejs/node
RUN set -ex \
  && for key in \
    9554F04D7259F04124DE6B476D5A82AC7E37093B \
    94AE36675C464D64BAFA68DD7434390BDBE9B9C5 \
    0034A06D9D9B0064CE8ADF6BF1747F4AD2306D93 \
    FD3A5288F042B6850C66B31F09FE44734EB7990E \
    71DCFD284A79C3B38668286BC97EC7A07EDE3FC1 \
    DD8F2338BAE7501E3DD5AC78C273792F7D83545D \
    B9AE9905FFD7803F25714661B63B535A4C206CA9 \
    C4F0DFFF4E8C1A8236409D08E73BC641CC11F4C8 \
  ; do \
    gpg --keyserver ha.pool.sks-keyservers.net --recv-keys "$key"; \
  done

ENV NPM_CONFIG_LOGLEVEL info
ENV NODE_VERSION 6.2.2

RUN curl -SLO "https://nodejs.org/dist/v$NODE_VERSION/node-v$NODE_VERSION-linux-x64.tar.xz" \
  && curl -SLO "https://nodejs.org/dist/v$NODE_VERSION/SHASUMS256.txt.asc" \
  && gpg --batch --decrypt --output SHASUMS256.txt SHASUMS256.txt.asc \
  && grep " node-v$NODE_VERSION-linux-x64.tar.xz\$" SHASUMS256.txt | sha256sum -c - \
  && tar -xJf "node-v$NODE_VERSION-linux-x64.tar.xz" -C /usr/local --strip-components=1 \
  && rm "node-v$NODE_VERSION-linux-x64.tar.xz" SHASUMS256.txt.asc SHASUMS256.txt

CMD [ "node" ]
```

You can always look at a `docker history` of the image in question to see more details about it's origin, but this doesn't give details about the contents from adds and copies into the image, which is typically how the base images are created:

```
$ docker history node:latest
IMAGE               CREATED             CREATED BY                                      SIZE                COMMENT
a6b9ffdcf522        5 weeks ago         /bin/sh -c #(nop) CMD ["node"]                  0 B                 
<missing>           5 weeks ago         /bin/sh -c curl -SLO "https://nodejs.org/dist   41.51 MB            
<missing>           5 weeks ago         /bin/sh -c #(nop) ENV NODE_VERSION=6.2.0        0 B                 
<missing>           5 weeks ago         /bin/sh -c #(nop) ENV NPM_CONFIG_LOGLEVEL=inf   0 B                 
<missing>           5 weeks ago         /bin/sh -c set -ex   && for key in     9554F0   78.62 kB            
<missing>           5 weeks ago         /bin/sh -c apt-get update && apt-get install    317.9 MB            
<missing>           5 weeks ago         /bin/sh -c apt-get update && apt-get install    122.6 MB            
<missing>           5 weeks ago         /bin/sh -c apt-get update && apt-get install    44.3 MB             
<missing>           5 weeks ago         /bin/sh -c #(nop) CMD ["/bin/bash"]             0 B                 
<missing>           5 weeks ago         /bin/sh -c #(nop) ADD file:5d8521419ad6cfb695   125.1 MB
```

Answer (score 1):

The difference between this 2 images is that the first, as you said pull an ubuntu image and install node. The second suppose to be an image with all the necessary things to run node already installed. Surely node:4.4.7 image uses an ubuntu image. But the idea it is to use an specific image for every specific task you do, on this way images are lighter to download and if the node image change you only download this part and not the hole ubuntu image. Also if you have another image using ubuntu for example java, grails, python, etc... you maintain ubuntu image without changes and an specific image for every technology.
The las reason is that all this specific images are constantly improved and you don`t need to change your dockerfiles just pull and use it.

Answer (score 1):

It's not really the same.
By taking a look at node:4.4.7's Dockerfile [here](https://github.com/nodejs/docker-node/blob/bf93fccf8e127824cd2478f491502c7d3ad0e1aa/4.4/Dockerfile) you can see that the node image is based on an debian jessie image in which several build packages are installed.
In that node image, it fetches the 4.4.7 nodejs targz from official site, whereas using apt-get, you won't get the same version. It depends in which node repo you added in your system